# RDP Windows 10 full windows size without scrollbars

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, scrollbar

After upgrading to windows 10, I noticed that one of my RDP settings no longer seems to have the same effect.

My screen size is 2560x1440.  I have 4 monitors, this is the first one to the left.

In windows 7, these settings opened the RDP in a window (ie not full screen) that took up part of the screen, but was the full height of the screen.  Basically it wasn't as wide as the screen but was still full height.

```
screen mode id:i:1
desktopwidth:i:1550
desktopheight:i:1160
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,-1566,0,0,1200
```

This left no space between the bottom of the window and the bottom of the screen, nor did it leave any space to the right of the window to the edge of the screen.

In Windows 10, these same settings leave about 7 pixels of extra space between the edges of the window and the edges of the screen...

[image]

Here you can see the calculator (grey) behind the RDP window.  You should not be able to... the RDP window should fit neatly into the corner of the screen.

I can't seem to find the settings to make this go away without resulting in both vertical & horizontal scroll bars.  The odd thing is that if I "pull" the height of the window down to the edge of the screen, the scroll bars vanish and the resulting window is the full height of the screen.

To do this, I add a little to the height as follows:

```
screen mode id:i:1
desktopwidth:i:1550
desktopheight:i:1167
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,-1566,0,0,1207
```

If I lessen then edge distance to make up for the space between the window edge and the screen edge, I get both scroll bars, but if I "pull" the edge of the window toward the edge of the screen, both scroll bars vanish and there is no space between the window or screen edge.  ie:

```
desktopwidth:i:1550
desktopheight:i:1160
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,-1559,0,0,1200
```

It's like it things for some reason there should be scroll bars, but when stretched out, it realizes they aren't needed after all and removes them.  Very odd.

This is frustrating because I don't want to have to resize the window every time I open it just to make the scroll bars disappear.

What am I missing here?  Are my winposstr settings off, or is this some weird window handling introduced in Windows 10?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way you can get RDP scroll bars to disappear is to have a guest system resolution small so that there is no need for scroll bars.

Comment: It seems as though I should be able to have the resolution at least as much as the screen height, less the title bar at the top of the window.  As described, if I stretch the window to it's full height the scroll bars go away.  I just want the window to open in this state initially.

Comment: That is how RDP works all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It didn't work this way in Win 7.  The behavior changed with the upgrade to Win 10.

Comment: That was many years ago so I honestly cannot remember accurately, but my recall is that scroll bars in RDP depended on the resolution used for the guest machine that RDP was accessing.